# How can I control what is passed to Navigator.pop() when clicking outside of a showModalBottomSheet?

Tags: flutter, dart, modal-dialog, future, navigator

I launch a modal bottom sheet, then use the data that is returned as its future.

```
var modalFuture = showModalBottomSheet(
                // ...
              );
              modalFuture.then((data) {
                // Use data
              });
```

I return data to it from the modal widget with:

```
Navigator.pop(context, data);
```

This is working well when completing the modal interaction with a widget I've set up.
I encounter my issue when clicking outside of the modal. Clicking outside of the modal causes the modal to dismiss automatically (with a `Navigator.pop(context)` call?). I am okay with this closing interaction, but I would like to send data back with it (with a `Navigator.pop(context, data)` call). Is there anyway to override the implicit pop when clicking outside of a showModalBottomSheet modal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your ModalWidget with WillPopScope. You can see the example below

```
 WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    Navigator.pop(context, data);
    return true; // return true if needs to be popped
  },
  child: ModelWidget(
    …
  ),
);
```

This will ensure that Navigator.pop is called when auto popped using the back button.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.